# unrecognized selector sent to instance error on button added to toolbar of subclassed ttphotoviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, three20, xcode4.3

I have subclass `TTphotoviewcontroller` and added a button for saving the images to the camera roll. All the other buttons on the toolbar are working fine (previous, next and play) except for the one I've created by overriding in the subclass file. I am getting the dreaded '**`unrecognized selector sent to instance`**' error when I click the button.

My subclass `TTphotoviewcontroller` is inside a navigation controller which in turn is inside a navigation controller of a `tabbarcontroller`.

The top nav controller has a view controller with an in-app purchase button. After purchase the user goes through to the wallpaper section containing the subclass `TTphotoviewcontroller` inside a navigation controller (hope that makes sense).

I have checked all the linker settings. I have used some of the code that can be found [here](http://sol3.typepad.com/tagalong_developer_journa/2009/12/adding-savetoalbum-to-the-ttphotoviewcontroller.html)

tabbar - navigation controller - in-app purchase view controller - navigation controller - subclass photoviewcontroller - `clickActionItem` selector method for button

I create the button like so:

```
     _clickActionItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction 
                          target:self action:@selector(clickActionItem)];
```

and fire with this:

```
    - (void) clickActionItem: (id)sender
 {
    NSURL *aUrl  = [NSURL URLWithString:[_centerPhoto URLForVersion:TTPhotoVersionLarge]];
                NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aUrl];
                UIImage  *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                NSLog(@"photo:class %@", [img class]);

                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is simple mistake by you that you are forgotten to give ':' after your @selector method.

```
_clickActionItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
                    UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
 target:self action:@selector(clickActionItem:)];
```

My suggestion will be that if you didn't create the selector method before calling it then always do copy and paste of the complete name of the method so this type of error can get reduced.

Comment: OK I'll try that when I get home. Why do the other buttons work without the colon? For example:  UIBarButtonItem* playButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
    UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(playAction)] autorelease];